Angular mat-form-field not working properly - mdc-notched-outline__notch shows overlapping border while using bootstrap
When using bootsrap 5 with Angular Material, the form fields have a top/bottom border overlapping the form field border.  I believe this is the mdc-notched-outline__notch class is conflicting with a bootstrap style.  If I remove the border it will have a gap in the form field border.  Any suggestions on how to fix?
Form Field Example
I added the following to global styles but it adds a gap to the border of the form field.
.mat-mdc-form-field.mat-mdc-form-field.mat-mdc-form-field.mat-mdc-form-field.mat-mdc-form-field .mdc-notched-outline__notch {
border-style: hidden;
}
Form Field Example when removing border style of notch

please share the minimal reproducible code, if possible a stackblitz where the issue happens
